# How to create a stratified sample for a boolean field with True, False and Null values?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, sample

I've a DataFrame with a boolean field.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [True],   
  [False],   
  [None],
  [True],   
  [False],
  [None]
]).toDF("match")
```

I want to create a stratified sample (PySpark) with equal True, False and Null values.

How can I also get the Null values in my sample (`None: 0.3` is not accepted)

```
sampled = df.sampleBy("match", fractions={True: 0.3, False: 0.3})
```

Comment: Many thanks. Nice solution. If you add this as answer I can accept it (and you also earn the bounty points ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.scala#L372) of `sampleBy` method, the parameter `fractions` is a `Map[T, Double]`, and for a MapType column with Spark, **null keys are not allowed** (see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/types/MapType.html))

```
def sampleBy[T](col: String, fractions: Map[T, Double], seed: Long): DataFrame = {
  sampleBy(Column(col), fractions, seed)
}
```

One possible solution is to add a flag to convert `False`, `True` and `NULL` to `0`, `1`, `2` and then do *sampleBy* based on this flag, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_sample = df.withColumn('flag', expr("coalesce(int(match), 2)")) \
    .sampleBy("flag", {0:0.3, 1:0.3, 2:0.3}) \
    .drop("flag")
```